# split values with commas to new lines in HTML

Tags: html

I have values in my HTML like so:

```
<div>{{countryname}}</div>
<div>{{countryactivity}}</div>
<div>{{countryactivitycount}}</div>
```

These values are already grouped and separated by a comma, e.g. "Country1, Country1, Country1"

The output looks like this:

```
Country1, Country1, Country1    
Activity1, Activity1, Activity2    
Count10, Count3, Count4
```

How can I get it to look like this:

```
| Country1 | Activity1 | Count10
| Country1 | Activity2 | Count3
| Country1 | Activity1 | Count4
```

I am new to HTML but can't seem to find an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a Table out of it and making them columns, but the easiest approach would be to use JavaScript. For example you can make a function that could replace commas with "|".

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with only HTML.you to need to write Javascript to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope below solution may help you somewhere for idea.

You can do it in HTML by using `.replaceAll('.',' | ')`

You have to put static `|` in the beginning and rest `,` will be replace by `|` using `replaceAll`

```
<div>| {{countryname.replaceAll('.',' | ')}}</div>
<div>| {{countryactivity.replaceAll('.',' | ')}}</div>
<div>| {{countryactivitycount.replaceAll('.',' | ')}}</div>
```

**It will render data horizontally without filtering/sorting but if you want to rearrange them then you need to use JavaScript.**

All the Best!